# trouble importing file from github to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

i tried importing the following project from github, there was practically error in every alternate line, in almost every file... almost all errors could be avoided using suppressors..  but some don't have any suggestions.. one such  error came in file DecodingAsyncTask.java line 50

```
decodeService = new DecodeServiceBase(new PdfContext());
```

with the following error msg 
[The constructor DecodeServiceBase(CodecContext) refers to the missing type CodecContext]

pls help..